# BufferedReader readLine() not working in a while loop

Tags: java, bufferedreader

When I call readLine() inside the while loop block, somehow, even when I pressed enter, the input won't finish. Looks like, it creates a new line but still waiting for the line input to be terminated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

  String line = "";
  while(!line.equals("End")){
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("String from keyboard not working : "+line+"\n");
  }
  
  while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println("String from keyboard in while loop : "+line+"\n");
  }
}
```

When I put readline() on top of while's condition section, it works fine.
I want to know why the former while doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what trouble you think you are having

But if I run your code at input

```
test
String from keyboard not working : test

End
String from keyboard not working : End

kkk
String from keyboard in while loop : kkk
```

Then if I input ctrl-d then the second loop will terminate

*even when I pressed enter,* `enter` does not terminate the input, try `ctrl-d`

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!line.equals("End")){
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("String from keyboard not working : "+line+"\n");
}
```

This block works fine. In this once you enter `End` it will Print End once and terminate. The reason for printing is that the condition is checked in the next cycle of the loop.

```
while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println("String from keyboard in while loop : "+line+"\n")
}
```

This block doesn't terminate because every time you hit Enter the terminal sends a Empty String. So if you want it to terminate when you press Enter change the condition to

```
while(!(line = br.readLine()).equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You called the **line** variable first before putting any data from the bufferedReader. the first while loop compares "END" with "", so, obviously wrong.